# Exporting MS Access 2016 form with empty fields to an Excel spreadsheet using SQL

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am exporting MS Access 2016 form data to an Excel spreadsheet.

```
Dim ctrlForm As Control
Dim sqlSelect As String
sqlSelect = "Select "

For Each ctrlForm  In Forms![Student Listing].Form.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrlForm  Is TextBox Then
        If ctrlForm .ColumnHidden = False Then
            ' this prints 109, which is text box - perfect
            Debug.Print "Control Type: " & ctrlForm .ControlType
            sqlSelect = sqlSelect & ctrlForm .Name & ","
        End If 'end if for hidden              
    End If 'end if for TypeOf
Next ctrlForm 

sqlSelect = Left(sqlSelect, Len(sqlSelect) - 1) 

sqlSelect = sqlSelect & " From " & Forms![Student Listing].Form.RecordSource

'prints the SQL statement - perfect too, all the view-able fields
Debug.Print "SQL Prompt: " & sqlSelect

Dim rs As Recordset
'errors here  with: Run-time error '3061' Too few parameters.
'Expected 1(or some other number) - even if there are 30 entries in the sqlSelect variable.
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlSelect)
```

If I hide all fields which may contain 'no data - or empty', it works.  The biggest issue is the middle initial, but I suspect looking for null/empty is the key. How do I go about doing that and keep the empty field(column) for the exported Excel file?

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong direction. Please post an example of a non-working SELECT string.

Comment: Select IDC,Last_Name,First_Name,Class_Department From New_Roster

Comment: Why don't you export directly from the recordsource of the form?

Comment: It is- the SELECT- FROM line is selecting visible columns selected by the user but from the New_Roster resource table

Answer (score 0):

"**Too few parameters**" means you have a field name specified, with no value (even an empty one - in this case, not enough commas in the data part of the string)

option 1: your only fault may be the space inbetween "ctrlForm .Name"

if that doesn't fix it, try:
a test if the control text is empty - when it is, write out an empty string (or an error message) and a comma, not skip the field.
so after the debug:

```
if .Name <> "" then
    sqlSelect = sqlSelect & ctrlForm .Name & ","
else 
    sqlSelect = sqlSelect & ","
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help. I found the issue.  The issue turned out to be date fields.  If I don't 'export' a date field, everything works. If a date field is exported - the error message I described above. Apparently, this is actually a known thing. The work around is to create a secondary 'text' field that contains the text of the date field. Export that field instead.  No loss of functionality, but the export works fine.